# Unexpected behavior of $parent.$index in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a code like this :

```
      <script type="text/ng-template" id="something.html">
         <div>
           Hey!
         </div>
     </script>

    <div ng-repeat="colum in columns">
   <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="list in column" id="{{$parent.$index}}" ng-include="something.html">
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

The ids are assigned as 1, 2, 3, 4 on the li elements. I am expecting that if columns has 4 elements then the ids for li inside a ul element should be 0,0,0,0.

Rendered DOM is something like :

```
<div>
   <ul>
      <li id="0">
      </li>
      <li id="1">
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div>
<ul>
   <li id="0">
   </li>
   <li id="1">
   </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

My expected DOM  :

```
<div>
   <ul>
      <li id="0">
      </li>
      <li id="0">
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div>
<ul>
   <li id="1">
   </li>
   <li id="1">
   </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Apologies if I missed something obvious.

Comment: Could you indent your code? Seeing flat HTML makes me nervous.

Comment: Thank you, done!

Comment: What is inside you `columns`? As your expected output **is** what is being output, see [here in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2x4aeqt/2/)

Comment: Apologies, I missed an important point in the question, I have an ng-include on all the lists. Updated now, truly sorry

Comment: @RamanS the rendered dom still has the expected ids, [check here](http://jsfiddle.net/r2x4aeqt/4/), maybe you're not putting the `'` around your ng-include?